# Drupal View/Block not displaying

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Another Drupal question: I have a View of type Term that outputs a block. It shows taxonomy items from a single vocabulary and the Preview of the View shows this content correctly. Whatever region I assign this block to, nothing displays. I've set a title and empty text in the View but those don't show either.

I created several blocks the same way and they all display fine but this is the only one that has View type Term, so I have a feeling it's related to this but can not find an explanation for it.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you double checked the blocks visibility settings? Maybe you accidentally checked the 'Show only on listed pages' or entered a linebreak in the pages textfield or something similar.

Comment: Have you set access control in the view/block?

Comment: Users cannot control whether or not they see this block + nothing checked for the roles + Show on every page except the listed pages but none listed

Comment: Access is 'Unrestricted'. Strange thing is that the preview outputs content so the query works ...

Comment: The next thing I would try is to use some of the built-in Views tools to try and debug (performance stats, sql signature); after that I would use some of the views module functions, for example 1) render the view manually in a template file using views\_embed\_view(), 2) examine views\_access() to see if it's a permissions problem, 3) maybe stick some print_r()'s in views\_block() to see what's happening.  There are some debug functions in the <a href="http://api.lullabot.com/file/contrib/views/views.module">views module</a>; they may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I have actually seen something like this before.  I ran into this a bit ago and had a dickens of a time fixing it.  My problem was that I was sorting based on node title AND I was telling it to sort based on node created time.  For some reason views only likes it when you sort by one and only one column.  Check that.

Finally if all else fails, there are still two options.

1) the devel module.  This module enables you to view sql dumps based on regions, etc.  (The themer is very useful as well).

2) Look at your watchdog logs.  Sometimes views throw errors from time to time.  Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I ended up just deleting the View and recreating it with success. Must have been a glitch somewhere, no idea what the original cause was ...

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with exposed filters removing my entire block display. Seems that removing the filters allowed the block to be viewed - still trying to get somewhere with them.

UPDATE - got somewhere with [this post](http://www.wildkatana.com/blog/drupal-embedding-nodes-views-and-blocks-tpl-files-or-nodes) - freakin sweet for putting a view in a custom tpl page.

Comment: Sorry about the necro. I was having the same problem (Drupal 7). The cause seems to have been that I had re-ordered the displays manually and for some reason this messed up the block display. Solution: I re-ordered the displays and it suddenly worked. Hopes this helps others in the same predicament.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my rss aggregation (second sidebar) to show everwhere by specifying that it show up "only" for <front> and content/* paths (I use the pathauto module if that matters).